# getting a blank string from output

Tags: python, string, return

I am having a hard time with understanding whats going on with this piece of code. the goal is to output a blank string if both of the names are missing. my code just outputs "Name: " no matter what i use for a return value????

```
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
    if len(first_name) and len(last_name) !=0:
        return "Name: " + str(last_name) +", " + str(first_name)
    elif len(last_name) == 0:
        return "Name: " + str(first_name)
    elif len(first_name) == 0:
        return "Name: " + str(last_name)
    else:
        return ""
```

Comment: You probably want to tag the specific language to get more eyes on your issue.

Comment: Please tag programming language you're using. That'd narrow down the specific auditory you want to target (and who want to see corresponding posts).

Comment: Note that `len(first_name) and len(last_name) !=0` is _not_ the same as `len(first_name) != 0 and len(last_name) != 0`, although in this specific case it actually behaves the same.

Comment: OK thanks, sorry first post.

Comment: @tobias_k In what case would `len(first_name) and len(last_name) !=0` _not_ be the same as `len(first_name)!=0 and len(last_name) !=0`?

Comment: @khelwood Maybe my comment was a bit unclear. Yes, that specific expression will _always_ be the same. I meant that the more general `if a and b == c` which pops up as a question about four and a half times a day, would not work as expected.

Comment: @tobias_k Agreed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if *both* strings are empty, then *one* string is empty, too. You have to re-arrange your conditions or the last one will never be triggered. Also, but unrelated to the problem, you can just check `if string` to check whether `string` is non-empty. Also, no need to convert the names to `str` (assuming that they are `str` already).

```
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
    if first_name and last_name: # both
        return "Name: " + last_name +", " + first_name
    elif not (first_name or last_name): # neither
        return ""
    elif last_name: # not both or neither, so only first
        return "Name: " + last_name
    else: # not both, neither, or first, so only last
        return "Name: " + first_name
```

For less `if/elif` "fun", you could filter and `join` the non-empty names, if any:

```
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
    present = [x for x in (last_name, first_name) if x]
    if present:
         return "Name: " + ", ".join(present)
    else:
         return ""
```

(The logic of that second one is also much simpler, as evident by the several mistakes I made in the first version, and less code-duplication, too.)

Comment: So I tested your new code and i get the same result as before. when I enter print(format_name("",""))  the output is "Name: " still??

Comment: @strebor71 Sorry, another error. Please test again _now_.

Answer (score 0):

I made a format_name function on my own. Please test it. I'd be very happy if you let me know opinion.

```
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
    name_list = [last_name, first_name]
    name_list = [name.strip() for name in name_list if name.strip()]
    full_name = ", ".join(name_list).strip()

    if full_name:
        return "Name: " + full_name
    else:
        return ""

first_name = ""
last_name = ""

full_name = format_name(first_name, last_name)
print(full_name)
```

Comment: You should know the result of running your code yourself before posting it.

Comment: I tested it before posting it. When first_name="" and last_name="", the result is "".

Comment: Hello, mkrieger1. What inputs did you use?

Comment: I can assure you that I did _not_ use your code when I posted my answer one minute before yours. Remember the Zen of Python: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." and this is it.

Comment: Yes it worked fine,  a bit humbling and also exciting for a noob to see different examples of how to use python. thanks for the help all.

Comment: Very glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rearrange the conditions to be able to check if both parts of the name are empty before you check for each individually.

```py
def f_n(first_name, last_name):
    if len(first_name) != 0 and len(last_name) !=0:
        return "Name: " + str(last_name) +", " + str(first_name)
    elif len(last_name) == 0 and len(first_name) == 0:
        return " "
    elif len(last_name) == 0:
        return "Name: " + str(first_name)
    else:
        return "Name: " + str(last_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def format(first_name, last_name):
if len(first_name) != 0 and len(last_name) !=0:
    return "Name: " + str(last_name) +", " + str(first_name)
if len(last_name) == 0 and len(first_name) == 0:
    return " "
if len(last_name) == 0:
    return "Name: " + str(first_name)
if len(first_name) == 0:
    return "Name: " + str(last_name)
```